# TourGuide and MenuItem from Menu.xml

Tags: android, xml

Im Trying to display the TourGuide (https://github.com/worker8/TourGuide/)
for a MenuItem that is in a ToolBar

my main_menu.xml ->

```
     <item
            android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:title="Busca"
            android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
            app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"

            app:showAsAction="always"
            ></item>


        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_facebook"
            android:title="Facebook"
            android:icon="@drawable/facebook"
            app:showAsAction="always"></item>
 <item
 android:id="@+id/action_settings" 
android:title="@string/action_settings"

        app:showAsAction="never" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_share"
            android:title="Compartilhar APP"
            android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha"
            app:showAsAction="never"></item>
```

for some reason i CANT use it on any other icons that doesnt have the "ActionViewClass" like the Search

The OnCreateOptions

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_atividade_principal, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        settings = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
...
}
```

if i use it in the `searchItem.getActionView();` it work like this:

```
TourGuide t1 = TourGuide.init(this).with(TourGuide.Technique.Click)
                .setPointer(new Pointer())
                .setToolTip(new ToolTip().setTitle("Settings").setDescription("Settingssssss ToolTip"))
                .setOverlay(new Overlay())
                .playOn(searchItem.getActionView());
```

but if i use it for the settings

```
.playOn(settings.getActionView());
```

i get a null pointer, why? i've saw the ActionClass at the Search MenuItem .XML, but even if i try .getTitle or anything else on the settings, it return a null pointer, WHY?

PS: dont want the ShowCase, its deprecated, TourGuide is active!

Comment: Hi did you got any solution, I am facing same problem.

Comment: Dont try to put a tourguide directly on to menu item and you are actually troubling the android OS coz onCreateMenuOption has to return true immediately after its called .. you should try to do any manupilation in this method for showcasing thtour.. and will lead to unnecessary disturbance in UI..

Comment: If you are still searching for the answer I will post it for you.. if yes, please respond to this comment

Comment: @DJphy yes please, it's too late for anyone to reply, but here's hoping..